# Dynamic array in vbscript gets cleared when control comes out of loop

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am newbie to VBScript. I am trying my hands at Dynamic array concept in VBScript below is my code.
Code:

```
dim arr()
For i = 0 To 3
    Redim arr(i+1,2)
    arr(i,0)=i
    arr(i,1)=i+1
    MsgBox arr(i,0)&"-"&arr(i,1)
Next
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    MsgBox arr(i,0)&" "&arr(i,1)
Next
```

As soon as the control comes into second loop all the values stored in arr are lost. i do not understand why and how? I've tried adding Preserve keyword but it throws subscript out of range error. TIA!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[oops, missed the two dimensions]
Use `ReDim Preserve` instead of plain `ReDim`. (And get rid of the () in the `Dim` statement.)
[/oops]

You can only grow dynamic arrays (not fixed arrays Dimmed with (n[,m,..])). A more dimensional array can only grow the last dimension ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)). So:

Option Explicit

```
ReDim arr(1, -1) ' <-- dynamic
Dim i
For i = 0 To 3
    ReDim Preserve arr(1, i) ' last dim grows
    arr(0, i) = i
    arr(1, i) = i + 1
Next
For i = 0 To 3
    WScript.Echo i & ":", arr(0, i), arr(1, i)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 29520636.vbs
0 0 1
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

Comment: removing () gives me error like Type Mismatch and i've already tried with Preserve keyword..it throws Subscript out of range error

Comment: did u try my above code in some .vbs file and ran at your end?

Comment: so you are saying we can grow only horizontally (columns) and not vertically (rows) ?

Comment: @MrunalGosar - just read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: thnx.. man..but it is quite strange that in the above code it works perfectly fine in the first loop but as soon as the control comes out of the loop it fails..quite weird

Comment: @MrunalGosar - that's because a ReDim **without Preserve** does **not preserve** the data (i.e. zaps the array).