# Can I set the limit of an array variable using another variable in Classic ASP/VB?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This works:

```
Dim list(9)
```

But this doesn't:

```
max_value = 9
Dim list(max_value)
```

How can I set the limit of this Array Variable using another integer variable (max_value)? I need to do this because the limit of list() will be the maximum value of an auto-incremented value from database.

Or, is it possible to don't set any limit? Or should I just set 999999 as the limit?

Comment: Try `Dim list(): Redim list(max_value)`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement an array in vbscript with a variable size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886681/how-to-implement-an-array-in-vbscript-with-a-variable-size)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you create an empty array first, you can then Redim the limit using a variable.

https://www.vbsedit.com/html/5c12ce79-6616-4144-b3b6-4cffe3884dfd.asp

```
Dim list()
max_value = 9
ReDim list(max_value)

list(0) = "bread"
list(1) = "cereal"
list(2) = "milk"

Msgbox list(1)
```